# Image on Canvas not showing

Tags: android, ondraw

I am fairly new to Android, but why isn't my image showing on the canvas?
I know that it is working properly because the background color is black, which I changed in the same same method, onDraw . Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

```
  public PongView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paddle1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pongpaddle);
    paddle2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pongpaddle);
}
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    xp1 = canvas.getWidth()/2;
    xp2 = canvas.getWidth()/2;
    yp1 = 25;
    yp2 = 760;
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(paddle1, xp1,yp1, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(paddle2,xp2,yp2, null);
    Paint white = new Paint();
    white.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawText("Score P1:"+ p1Score +" P2: " + p2Score , 700, 20,white );  
}
```

Comment: Try to log canvas.getWidth()

Comment: Check your ADB Logcat, and see if any exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: I figured out that The whole method doesn't work, because if I commented out the "canvas.drawColor("Color.BLACK");.  The background was still black. Or if I changed the color, it would still be black. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment above, I think what's happening is, android run time is drawing to the canvas, and your `onDraw` is not being called. You can avoid this by calling `this.setWillNotDraw(false)` in your class' constructor. Once you clear this flag, your onDraw() will be called.

**Source:** Android developer docs says if you override View's `onDraw()`, you have to clear this flag. Check [setWillNotDraw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw%28boolean%29)

Comment: I did what you said and included the @Override and it worked.